# Why was my question to reopen another question deleted from Meta

Tags: support

Within the last month, I asked a question about reopening [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/59607/775).

I stand in utter amazement that somehow my valid Meta question disappeared.

I ask:

- Why was my meta question deleted?
- Who did this?

I formally request from Stack Exchange employees (not local Network Engineering mods) that this question is reinstated.

Speaking as a former moderator of this site I know very well that there is no excuse for a Meta question like this to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did delete that question as it was simply a request to have the question reopened and I reopened the question as a result.

I chose to delete it as there was no discussion and I saw no additional value that question provided to future users.

As you clearly feel strongly enough to post about the deletion, I will go ahead and undelete it now.

Comment: I appreciate the forthright "Yes I did it"; however, I strongly disagree about your position of the throwaway value of meta questions.  SE meta discussions serve as a "historical record of moderation" (among other things).   Those should be permanent records, available to the whole community.

Comment: If there were actual discussion in that meta question, I would agree with you. However, in this case it served no more purpose than if a user raised a flag on the question making the assertion or posted a comment to the question. Neither of which become part of the permanent record available to the whole community once they are dealt with appropriately.

Comment: Re:  _in this case it served no more purpose than if a user raised a flag on the question_  I will repeat, a big part of SE meta discussions are a record of how this site has been moderated.  If you think this is a debatable point, I'll be happy to take my grievance to Stack Exchange meta.  However, as a long-time user in this community, I already know what that outcome will be:  "Mr Site moderator, please don't do that again." (assuming there was no abuse, or other ToS violations in the aforementioned question).